# Automatically update status without page refresh in PHP, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I would like to know how can I update a table column automatically when a button is pushed to change its status.

My example: I have a button which exports data from the table of those columns selected and once the file begins to download I want a certain field in the table to update automatically with "Exported".

This is what I have coded up to this point without the integration of the automatic process (Right now it updates the status but you have to refresh the page for it to take effect).

Its a project inside joomla so there is a Model, Controller and a View.

Model Code:

```
public function export_to_csv($result, $values) {

    $headers="";

if ($values->export_csv == 1){
     $headers = "order_number|first_name|middle_name|last_name|email|shipment_name|payment_name|created_on|modified_on|order_status|order_total|virtuemart_order_id \n";

    }


    $shtml="";

        for ($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){

            if ($result[$i]["export_status"] == 0 || $values->mark_csv == 0){

    $shtml = $shtml.$result[$i]["order_number"]. "|" .$result[$i]["first_name"]. "|" .$result[$i]["middle_name"]. "|" .$result[$i]["last_name"]. "|" .$result[$i]["email"]. "|" .$result[$i]["shipment_name"]. "|" .$result[$i]["payment_name"]. "|" .$result[$i]["created_on"]. "|" .$result[$i]["modified_on"]. "|" .$result[$i]["order_status"]. "|" .$result[$i]["order_total"]. "|" .$result[$i]["virtuemart_order_id"]. "\n";


            }
        }

        if ($shtml == ''){

            echo "false";

        }else{

            $shtml=$headers.$shtml;
            $_SESSION['txtDownload']=$shtml;

            echo "true";
        }

    exit;

}
```

Controller Code:

```
public function startDownload(){

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $q = "SELECT prefix_csv FROM #__virtuemart_kiala_settings";
    $db->setQuery($q);
    $date = date("Ymd");

    $result=$db->loadResult();

    $shtml="";
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" .$result."_".$date. ".csv");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: BINARY");    
    $shtml = $_SESSION['txtDownload'];

    echo $shtml;
    unset($_SESSION['txtDownload']);

    exit;

}
```

View Code:

```
jQuery('#download').click(function() {

    var checks = countChecks();

    var checkCount = serializeChecks(checks);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "index.php?option=com_virtuemart&controller=kiala&task=prepareDownload",
        type: "post",
        data: checkCount,
        success: function(data){

            if (data=="true"){
                document.location.href = 'index.php?option=com_virtuemart&controller=kiala&task=startDownload';


            }else{
                alert('Error initializing download.');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do, but if you just want to update a table when a button is pressed then you simply put the update sql in your ajax response php.  AFAICS the start download function would appear to be the appropriate spot for it.

Comment: Please use Joomla 2.5 coding standards for your database query!